# Error: Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'AppComponent'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, django, typescript

I am trying to use Django with Angular2. I have a working Django project. I am getting this error while trying to use Angular2 with it:

> Error: Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'AppComponent'.
>   at new BaseException (http://user:8000/ng/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:5116:27)
>   at NgModuleResolver.resolve (http://user:8000/ng/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:12956:27)
>   at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://user:8000/ng/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:13200:51)
>   at RuntimeCompiler._compileComponents (http://user:8000/ng/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:15845:51)
>   at RuntimeCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (http://user:8000/ng/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:15769:41)
>   at RuntimeCompiler.compileModuleAsync (http://user:8000/ng/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:15746:25)
>   at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone (http://user:8000/ng/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:9991:29)
>           at PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule (http://user:8000/ng/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:9984:25)
>           at Object.eval (http://user:8000/ng/src/main.js:5:53)
>           at eval (http://user:8000/ng/src/main.js:17:4)
>       Evaluating http://user:8000/ng/src/main.js
>       Error loading http://user:8000/ng/src/main.js

Part of package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common":  "2.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/compiler":  "2.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/core":  "2.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
"@angular/http":  "2.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/platform-browser":  "2.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "2.0.0-rc.5",
"@angular/router":  "3.0.0-beta.2",
"@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.2",
"@angular/upgrade":  "2.0.0-rc.5",

"systemjs": "0.19.27",
"core-js": "^2.4.0",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
"zone.js": "^0.6.12",

"angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.15",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.6"},
```

main.ts:

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import {appRouterProviders} from "./app/app.route";
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from "@angular/http";
import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module'; <-- Added this as per an answer below. Error is still there. 
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { routes } from './app.routes';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule,FormsModule,HttpModule, 
RouterModule.forRoot( ROUTES, { useHash: true } ) ],
declarations: [ AppComponent ],
bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

index.html:

```
<script>
  window.ANGULAR_URL = "{{ ANGULAR_URL }}";
  System.import('/ng/src/main.js').catch(function(err){
      console.error(err);
  });
</script>
```

I have set ANGULAR_URL in `settings.py` file of Django. It shows /ng/ on browser. I searched a lot and tried changing the dependencies in `package.json` so many times. I made sure I did `npm install` every time I made changes in `package.json`. I have seen many syntax changes with different versions. If this  might be the issue, here are the npm and node versions I am using:
`npm 4.1.1`  and `node v4.8.3`. I am running Django on port 8000.

app.component.ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `
    <h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>
    <nav>
      <a routerLink="/component1" routerLinkActive="active">Component 1</a>
      <a routerLink="/component2" routerLinkActive="active">Component 2</a>
    </nav>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
`,
directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

**UPDATE-1**

scripts part of package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
"start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
"docker-build": "docker build -t ng2-quickstart .",
"docker": "npm run docker-build && docker run -it --rm -p 3000:3000 -p 3001:3001 ng2-quickstart",
"pree2e": "npm run webdriver:update",
"e2e": "tsc && concurrently \"http-server -s\" \"protractor protractor.config.js\" --kill-others --success first",
"lint": "tslint ./app/**/*.ts -t verbose",
"lite": "lite-server",
"postinstall": "typings install",
"test": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
"test-once": "tsc && karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
"tsc": "tsc",
"tsc:w": "tsc -w",
"typings": "typings",
"webdriver:update": "webdriver-manager update"
},
```

By the way, I have been following [this](https://4sw.in/blog/2016/django-angular2-tutorial/) to use Angular with Django.

**UPDATE-2**

I have just realised that my tsconfig.json and typings.json are not in same place. I put both in same place as package.json is present. Now I am getting the following error :

> error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'lib'.

**UPDATE-3**

tsconfig.json file:

```
{
 "compilerOptions": { 
 "target": "es5",
 "module": "commonjs",
 "moduleResolution": "node",
 "sourceMap": true,
 "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
 "experimentalDecorators": true,
 "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
 "noImplicitAny": true,
 "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
 }
}
```

And my `tsc -v` gives `Version 2.1.5`. Now I have changed the `"typescript": "^1.8.10",` to `"typescript": "^2.1.5"`. So the error mentioned in update -2 i not there but it shows this:

> Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'forRoot' of undefined
>
> Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'forRoot' of undefined
>           at Object.eval (http://user:8000/ng/src/app/app.module.js:22:114)
>           at eval (http://user:8000/ng/src/app/app.module.js:29:4)
>           at eval (http://user:8000/ng/src/app/app.module.js:30:3)
>           at eval (anonymous)
>       Evaluating http://user:8000/ng/src/app/app.module.js
>       Evaluating http://user:8000/ng/src/main.js
>       Error loading http://user:8000/ng/src/main.js

Comment: can you post also your app.component.ts?

Comment: I have included app.component.ts file.

Answer (score 0):

You are not importing `AppModule` in your main.ts. And you were probably bootstrapping `AppComponent` which was causing the error you see.

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import {appRouterProviders} from "./app/app.route";
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from "@angular/http";
import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Comment: Importing AppModule in main.ts is not making any difference. It was a mistake while copying my code. I added it now in my question.

Comment: Did you compile after the change? The error indicates you are trying to bootstrap `AppComponent`

Comment: Yes. I did compile. I have also seen suggestions on scripts in package.json but none of them worked. So lemme show mine to see if there exists an error in that.

Comment: Then, I suspect its not getting compiled now. What could be the reason for this ?

Comment: How are you compiling? Are you seeing any compilation errors? Post your tsconfig,json and your `tsc  --version`

Comment: I have included tsconfig.json file and  mentioned tsc -v in update-3.

Comment: No errors but I see these suggestions after this `> tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" `

Version 2.3.2
Syntax:   tsc [options] [file ...]

Examples: tsc hello.ts
          tsc --outFile file.js file.ts
          tsc @args.txt Options: etc

Comment: Also I have my typescript compiler running in watch mode : `"tsc:w": "tsc -w"` which is supposed to do auto compilation upon any change. What is that I am missing here ?